# How to use state in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in react js. I want to know how to initialize state variable and how I can use state variable in html. 
Please help me how ever knows it.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can find the answer in the official documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow this example. I have written a very simple component that will help you to understand state in react.

```
import React, {Component, useEffect, useState} from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {names: []};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let json = [];
        json.push("Taj");
        json.push("Hamilton");
        json.push("John");
        this.setState({names: json});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                {this.state.names.map((item, i) => {
                    return <li key={i}>
                        {item}
                    </li>
                })}
            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of initializing state:

```
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {date: new Date()};   
    }
```

This sets a property in the state called 'date', and initializes it with the current date.

To access it, you must render the HTML:

```
     render() {
         return (
           <div>
             <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
             <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
           </div>
         );   
     }
```

This renders HTML which accesses the `date` property on the `state` object; specifically, the `toLocaleTimeString()` function on the date object.

Source: the documentation, at https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html.