# is there anyway i can define state in this case

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props, setstate

How do I define state for the given class component for the listed data?
PS still a beginner.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Card, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import './AccountsCards.css'

class AccountsCards extends React.Component{
render(){

   
    const data=[
            {
                mail : 'xya@gmail.com',
                password : 'hjhjsa87',
                recovery : 'xxa@gmail.com'
            },
            {
                mail : 'xya@gmail.com',
                password : 'hjhjsa87',
                recovery : 'xxa@gmail.com'
            },
            {
                mail : 'xya@gmail.com',
                password : 'hjhjsa87',
                recovery : 'xxa@gmail.com'
            },
        ]



            return(
            data.map((listValue, i) => {
            return(
                <Card className="acard">
                    <Row className="acc-card-row">
                        <Col sm={4}>
                        {listValue.mail}
                        </Col>
                        <Col sm={4}>
                        {listValue.password}
                        </Col>
                        <Col sm={4}>
                        {listValue.recovery}
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Card>
                    )    
                }
            )
        )
    }
}


export default AccountsCards
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use state in react project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61148716/how-to-use-state-in-react-project)

Comment: this answer seems applicable, thankyou

Answer (score 1):

By defining your state in the constructor of the React component like this.

```
class AccountsCards extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [
        {
          mail: "xya@gmail.com",
          password: "hjhjsa87",
          recovery: "xxa@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          mail: "xya@gmail.com",
          password: "hjhjsa87",
          recovery: "xxa@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          mail: "xya@gmail.com",
          password: "hjhjsa87",
          recovery: "xxa@gmail.com"
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.data.map((listValue, i) => {
      return (
        <Card className="acard">
          <Row className="acc-card-row">
            <Col sm={4}>{listValue.mail}</Col>
            <Col sm={4}>{listValue.password}</Col>
            <Col sm={4}>{listValue.recovery}</Col>
          </Row>
        </Card>
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add state = data under your data initialization.

You can call data by referencing `this.state`.

E.g.

`this.state.map(dataItem => {})`